# Automatically drop reverted commits on rebase

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, git-rebase

Is there any way to automatically drop reverted commits when rebasing?

git log: (from recent to old)

```
4321: revert another bad commit
3210: revert bad commit
6666: another useful commit
7777: some useful commit
0123: another bad commit 
1234: bad commit
```

Can I get

```
6666: another useful commit
7777: some useful commit
```

without manual actions for every commit/revert pair?

Comment: You do know that you can delete the lines corresponding to the commits you do not want from the text editor that opens when you run `git rebase -i`?

Comment: Related, if not (more general) duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220368/how-to-automagically-remove-commits-that-cancel-themselves-out

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [*auto squash*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autosquash) feature of the `git rebase` command to your advantage.

This would require an additional step beforehand, however, when creating the reverting commits:

Suppose you want to revert commit `1234`. Instead of doing

```
git revert 1234
```

or the equivalent from a graphical interface, you need to split this into

```
git revert --no-commit 1234
git commit --fixup 1234
```

Or you would need to edit the commit message manually to begin with "fixup!".

Now, when using `git rebase -i --autosquash`, or when the `rebase.autoSquash` option is enabled, the reverting commit will be automatically squashed with the original commit `1234`. If the two cancel each other out exactly, the resulting commit will be empty.

By doing the same rebase a second time, the now empty commit will automatically be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I am facing is:

```sh
git checkout 7777 -B new-branch
git reset --hard 6666
```

So the log will look as you expect.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I fixed it!

Comment: This does the same as `git checkout 6666 -B new-branch` and doesn't remove `1234` and `0123`.