# commit certain files to new branch

Tags: git

Let's say I have the following 4 files on my `master` branch

```
$ ls
README.txt documentation.html main.py docs/main.html

$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/master
```

Q. What are the set of commands I should run to commit ONLY the html files `documentation.html` and `docs/main.html` to a separate branch `gh-pages` in a way such that it destroys the existing branch and creates a single commit containing those files? I would also like to push them to the remote machine. Is it possible to do this without running `git checkout gh-pages`?

My current solution for this is to use the following commands

```
git branch -D gh-pages || echo "Delete local branch failed. It is possible that local branch exists"
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git rm --cached $(git ls-files) # unstage existing files

# Currently using python add_files.py to do this instead
# subprocess.call('git add {}'.format(html_file)')
find . -name '*.html' | xargs git add 

git commit -m "Commit all html files. This commit message does not matter"

git reset $(git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -m "Generate Sphinx Documentation") # Creates a single commit from current branch
git push --set-upstream origin gh-pages --force
git clean -fxd # Since I unstaged existing files, they will cause conflicts on running the next command if not removed
git checkout master

git pull # Just to make sure master and origin/master are in sync
```

This is not elegant in my opinion, but it works. I was wondering if there were a better way to do this? The purpose of this "script" is to generate documentation on a ContinuousIntegration server and push the documentation to a `gh-pages` branch on the remote repository to take advantage of GitHub pages or GitLab pages. I'm not concerned about the history of the gh-pages branch.

Thoughts?

Comment: `git push -f origin gh-pages` after you create the local branch. Or you can just `git push origin :gh-pages` to delete the remote branch first if you don't want the `-f` flag.

Comment: You can squash all existing commits into one on a branch with `git rebase -i`

Comment: `git rebase -i` will not work if I'm using Travis-CI or Jenkins. The equivalent `git rebase --root` will only merge all commits except the root commit into one, leaving two commits on the branch.

Comment: Acutally it will if you do something like `EDITOR=touch git rebase -i`. Use `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` instead of `EDITOR` for newer versions.

Comment: Wouldn't that still require interaction? You still need to tell git which commits need to be squashed onto the previous commit, right?

Comment: Nope. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25938711/2988730

Comment: Oh. I see. But then how do you expect to do this on Jenkins to begin with?

Comment: The best you can do is to write a script that can figure out which commits to mark for squashing.

Comment: The way I've described it currently in the question works on Jenkins. I was just curious if there was a more terse way of doing it. For example, [ghp_import](https://github.com/davisp/ghp-import/blob/master/ghp_import.py) seems to be doing something similar but it works on an entire folder.

Answer (score -1):

For adding only html files, you can simply run `git add *.html`.

> in a way such that it destroys the existing branch and creates a single commit containing those files?

By this I guess you are just concerned with the current state of your files, but I won't suggest doing that. Maintaining a history is always helpful. However, you can always do `git push -f origin gh-pages` after  amending **gh-pages** branch locally. In this way your branch will always be containing a single commit with your most recent changes.

> Is it possible to do this without running `git checkout gh-pages`?

Well, you are currently doing it but its quite verbose. Give [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933392/5107319) a look. Although checking out to the branch will also save you from doing `git reset` and `git clean` as you are doing in your current approach.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. There is a tool that seemingly does the same thing - [ghp_import](https://github.com/davisp/ghp-import/blob/master/ghp_import.py). However it does not seem to take a list of files as an input and appears to work on an entire folder instead.